# How can I change the back button image in the navigation bar for iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uinavigationbar, ios13

[On the right, the first time and on the left, all the other times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tts0y.jpg)

Hello Guys,  I’m new so I hope that’s the way things goes around here !

Like y’all know, iOS 13 introduced UI changes. We have an app in production and I recently woke up (maybe a little too late haha) and as I compiled and launch it on a freshly updated iOS 13 device, that’s when I became aware there was some work to do !   I handled the dark mode by not enabling it, I handled my modals but there is one thing I can’t seem to make like iOS 12 and it’s my Navigation Bar UI.

We use a custom back button image and after fighting during several hours, I finally succeeded but it’s ok everytime except the first time. I will always have the default icon the first time, and then when I come back to the same controller, it’s okay.

Here is a photo (at the beginning of the question) so you can understand and also my code ! 
I know it’s possible to use Appearance for specific VC with « whenContained » but I can’t seem to figure it out cause it’s all in navigation controller and I don’t know how to differentiate them.

```swift
fileprivate func navigationBarWithBackgroundColor(_ backgroundColor: UIColor, TintColor tintColor: UIColor, displayBackButtonIfNeeded: Bool, BackImage imageName:String, displayShadowBar: Bool = false) {

        let backButtonImage = UIImage(named: imageName)

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {

            let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            appearance.backgroundColor = backgroundColor

            appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: tintColor]
            appearance.setBackIndicatorImage(backButtonImage, transitionMaskImage: backButtonImage)
            appearance.shadowImage = displayShadowBar ? UIImage(named:"") : UIImage()

            let back = UIBarButtonItemAppearance()
            // hide back button text
            back.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear]
            appearance.backButtonAppearance = back

            navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = tintColor
            navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
            navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = appearance
            navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance

        } else {
            if displayBackButtonIfNeeded {
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = backButtonImage
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backButtonImage
                self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: nil, action: nil)

            } else {
                self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
            }

            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = backgroundColor
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = tintColor
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:""), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = displayShadowBar ? UIImage(named:"") : UIImage()
        }
    }
```

I’m basically become crazy here and I assume I’m missing something very obvious so if you guys have any hints or clues except apple documentation, feel free to share :)

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 7):

In iOS 13 you can set up back button image and transition mask image only by the function

```
func setBackIndicatorImage(UIImage?, transitionMaskImage: UIImage?)
```

And here is an example

```
standartAppearence.setBackIndicatorImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "backButton"), transitionMaskImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "backButton"))
```